# Getting 502 Bad Gateway from an Apigee server

Tags: node.js, express, request, apigee

My application is running Node.js **v12.22.1** with Express, MongoDB and Vue.js. An Apigee server is serving as a gateway between the backend and the client.

If a request takes more than 2 minutes to complete (which can happen if the backend calls another backend service, that does some long calculations), it yields *502 Bad Gateway* on the front-end.  This problem occurs exactly 2 minutes into the request, so I assume the timeout is the problem. In my version of node, [the default timeout is 2 minutes](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout).

The 502 error is not logged anywhere on the backend. The backend actually fulfills the request and logs a 200 Ok in about 4 minutes (but the client have already received an error at this point).

Error body:

```
{
   "fault":{
      "faultstring":"Unexpected EOF at target",
      "detail":{
         "errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.UnexpectedEOFAtTarget"
      }
   }
}
```

This error is described in [the Apigee docs](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/troubleshoot/runtime/502-bad-gateway), which leads me to believe that the intermediate Apigee server is the source of this error.

I've used the [timeout middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/timeout.html) to increase request timeout to 10 minutes. The server now responds with 503 if the inbound request exceeds the timeout. This solves the problem, but there are still things I don't quite understand.

**The question:** If I configure the timeout on the backend, how come the error is thrown by Apigee, not by the backend itself? Let's omit the possibility of a logging problem and assume logging is fine.

P.S. I've also raised keep-alive on the backend as [suggested by the Apigee docs](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/troubleshoot/runtime/502-bad-gateway#incorrect-keep-alive-timeout). It had no effect on the problem.

P.P.S I understand that having requests that take 2+ minutes is not ideal, but that's what I'm stuck with for now.